# How do I model a fact with start/end dates to relate to a daily measure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, data-modeling, business-intelligence, dimension

So I have a Sales Cube with Sales By Item By Day.

I want to bring in Bookings/Orders and compare those to the sales to see if we are booking the right numbers.

The bookings fact is a single record with an OnDate, OffDate, Quantity, Item.

I want to be able to select a given week, show sales for that week and any bookings that were in effect for that week.

My current configuration is to have a many-to-many relationship with the Date dimension. I created a view that takes my bookings and generates a record for every day between on and off.  As you can imagine, this is a large table, and will get larger in production.

With this I still have to set my SaleDate, OnDate, and OffDate filters explicitly which gets cumbersome when browsing the cube.

Is there a better way to be handling this?

Here is an shot of my DSV to help see what I have set up.

[image]

Comment: Why do you still need to set the OnDate and OffDate filters explicitly?

Comment: If I want to pick a given sale day or week and show all bookings that were effective for that time. On date and off date aren't related to the Date dimension because that would generate role playing dimensions and I don't think those work for what I'm trying to do. So after picking a sale date I then add on date and off date to my filters and pick the ones I want to see during that period.

Comment: So if OnDate and OffDate aren't related to the date dimension, what are you using for the SaleDate column in the FACT_BookingsByDay column when you generate it from the FACT_Bookings table. I was under the impression that you break down the FACT_Bookings table and create daily records in FACT_BookingsByDay table with SaleDate set for each day within the OnDate - OffDate range.

Comment: Wow...I had posted this a while ago. Just went to my cube and yeah...don't need to explicitly set on/off dates. You're absolutely right. The question still remains - is there a better way to do this?